# Trac task context sharing with mylyn

Tags: svn, task, trac, mylyn

I've got trac working with mylyn (in eclipse obviously) through xmlrpc.  Yay for six hours of my life.  I can attach and retrieve context to tasks in trac.

Question setup: I have a project checked out into two workspaces.  In workspace 1, I activate a task, open some files, edit some stuff, commit the changes to svn, and attach the context to the task.

In workspace 2, I update from svn, retrieve the context of a task and activate it.  The correct files show in the Package Explorer (on the left), but the files (which I left open in workspace 1) do not open automatically and the cursor isn't placed at the last edit point.

Is it possible to get trac working that way?  I checked this test project out from svn into two different workspaces in the exact same way to test this functionality out - I read something about project names needing to be the same so I eliminated that variable.  It seems as if the way it's working now is still pretty great, but it would be even better if I could get it that last step.

ps question:  I didn't setup the postcommit hooks from svn to trac yet because it seems like all they do is update ticket status for you.  Am I missing some other cool thing they can do, or maybe updating ticket status is a bigger deal than I think it is?

Comment: Is this question unclear?  Please let me know so I can reword it if it's bad, or leave a comment if you use it the way I'm describing.

Comment: FYI, this is from a few years ago.  I just set up trac + mylyn with xmlrpc yesterday, and it took something like half an hour.  Things have gotten better.

Answer (score 1):

The files should be reopened, but I believe Mylyn currently doesn't supports setting cursor position in any editors. You'll have to submit bug reports and enhancement requests back to the project. See http://eclipse.org/mylyn/support/